# Cloud Drive alternatives (Bitcasa)

Tags: hard-drive, sync, symbolic-link, storage, cloud

So I've been using a company called Bitcasa to store my data in the cloud. Recently got an email stating they are shutting down their personal packages and that I need to move my data.

I had been thinking about moving anyway as their service is somewhat lacking, but they have features I like.

The issue I'm having is finding an alternative that does the same.

The biggest feature about Bitcasa, is that it does not have to have a sync folder. It works exactly like plugging a new drive into the computer. This meant, no matter the size of the PC, I could access over 1TB of data. They also had some mirror options, where you could select a folder and mirror it to the drive.

I've looked at a lot of providers and cannot seem to find anything that offer this type of service. 
I have tried Google Drive but the desktop application is terrible. 
You can only install it in the base location, you cannot include other files out of this base location, and it syncs, meaning if I want to access the 1TB of data I have in the cloud, I need 1TB of free space, in the location its installed it.

I have tried mklink's and junctions and symlinks, but the app just doesnt like them and on reboot of the PC, it fails to sync correctly.

I've had a look at Dropbox, ICloud, IDrive, SkyDrive and Box, but if they offer this type of online storage, its not in their features or FAQ's.

Any help would be great!

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: 1) Dropbox has in latest beta for placeholders of files. Your Dropbox folder will contain the names of all the files you have in the cloud. Files synced locally will just have green checkmark but those only in the cloud will also have a cloud icon. If you double-click on cloud icon, it will download. Adding folders outside of Dropbox is like you said not ideal. 2) Bittorrent Sync is free and will let you sync any folder and doesn't have a formal hierarchy structure. Ideal for sharing a specific project folder or a parent folder like documents. 3) Also look at iSCSI for actual cloud drive.

Comment: Wow, that was the 2nd time Bitcasa let their customers down big time. Too bad you apparently didn't know about [their first failure](https://web.archive.org/web/20141024022311/http://blog.bitcasa.com/2014/10/23/important-we-are-upgrading-storage-infrastructure-and-need-you-to-take-action/) in which people lost data as they were not notified at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..."Is that it does not have to have a sync folder. It works exactly like plugging a new drive into the computer."...

That feature is called [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV).

Google Drive supports WebDAV with 3rd party tools, but I will go for a native integration. Get again to the FAQs and look for WebDAV.

I'm using ownCloud, but you need a VPS...

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Ive used ownlcloud before. Since you are looking for 1tb of space you could check out [ByteonSite](https://www.byteonsite.com/) they have packages of 1tb-5tb of storage options with unmetered inbound. and 1-5tb off outbound traffic. You could set up Owncloud on a Linux based VPS. And be set.

Comment: I ended up using netDrive2 to enable webDAV through to Google drive, thanks for the suggestion.